# Angularjs : set date format with zone

Tags: angularjs

In my controller , i would like to get a date with pattern

> 2018-03-07T00:00:00.000Z

I have tried : `$filter('date')(date, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ');`
But it's not working, I am getting :

> 2018-03-07T00:00:00.000+0100

Comment: please post you format in which you would like to convert date

Comment: try `new Date(date).toJSON()`

Comment: It is working {{'1288323623006' | date:'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ'}}

Comment: I am also posting using $filter

Comment: The Z will give you the the 4 digit timeZone.In which format you want? Or you can try `$filter('date')(new Date(input), 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.sssZ');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this conversion you may use javascript function
var date = new Date()
date.toISOString()

instead of using javascript $filter may be something wrong out there

Comment: well I am sending this value to my Spring MVC server. Java can parse : ZonedDateTime.parse("2018-03-07T00:00:00.000Z"); but not 2018-03-07T00:00:00.000+0100, that's why I need to send the date with the Z at the end.

Comment: Basically the format ou want has z in the end which means offset so java or any other framework validates and sets the time accrodingly so that you may be able to retrive in local time as per user standard if you use ISOString it will same as $filter

Comment: If it resolves your problem please accept and upvote my answer and post if u require further help